# In Spider chart, how can change axis scale to be increasing by 5 instead of 1?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection, tkz-kiviat

I have the following Latex code to plot a spider cart. However, I need the Scale increasing by 5, in other words; 0,5,10,... and so on, instead of being increased by 1.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style={gray!50}, scale=0.2, gap=1, lattice=35]{A,B,C,D,E,F}

\tkzKiviatLine[ ultra thick, color=red,   mark=ball,  ball color=red,mark size=12pt](5,5,5,5,5,5)
\tkzKiviatLine[ ultra thick, color=blue,  mark=ball,  ball color=red,mark size=12pt](10,10,10,10,10,10)   
\tkzKiviatLine[ ultra thick, color=gray,  mark=ball,  ball color=red,mark size=12pt](15,15,15,15,15,15) 
\tkzKiviatLine[ ultra thick, color=green, mark=ball,  ball color=red,mark size=12pt](20,20,20,20,20,20)   
\tkzKiviatLine[ ultra thick, color=yellow,mark=ball,  ball color=red,mark size=12pt](25,25,25,25,25,25)   
\tkzKiviatLine[ ultra thick, color=pink  ,mark=ball,  ball color=red,mark size=12pt](30,30,30,30,30,30)   

\tkzKiviatGrad[](6)  

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following work

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat} 

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /kiviatgrad/simplify label/.code={
        \ifx\nv\undefined\else
            \pgfmathparse{Mod(\nv,5)}
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt>0pt
                \tikzset{opacity=0}
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzKiviatDiagram[radial style/.style={gray!50}, scale=0.2, gap=1,, lattice=35]{A,B,C,D,E,F}
    \tkzKiviatGrad[simplify label=5](6)  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

As @percusse suggests, you should add `%` at the end of each line. Otherwise there might be extra space in the final result. I do not know particularly which line feed causes the extra space. So the best way is to keep `%` on all lines.

Comment: you might need a few `%` signs though ;)

Comment: @percusse at which part? I thought spaces do not harm in `tikzpicture`!

Comment: I might have misjudged it but i think if you check the result on the article class the picture should be shifted to the right a few whitespaces since the code has newlines. independent from the TikZ parser.